# How to install OwnCloud 8 in CentOS 6 runs on Parallels Plesk 12 with MySQL Database?

Tags: mysql, centos6, plesk, parallels, owncloud

The installation from Terminal works and the web page also but after finishing with Admin Password and Database Info can't log in to OwnCloud.

The OwnCloud App Work with same credentials but web interface shows noting.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you configured ownCloud with the same credentials as the login for your database? In other words; do you have configured your database-access correctly?

You can reset your password on the lostpassword-page, if you remember your admin username.

Edit:
ownCloud doesn't like CloudFlare as it doesn't seem to load static files like JS and CSS correctly. Might as well be a problem, as it was for me.

Comment: That's the problem. I browser I get nothing(no error message or the lost password). But with the same credential I access it from ownCloud app from Mac.

Comment: How do you mean 'nothing'? Is the webpage empty? No HTML-error? What does the web inspector look like? You might want to check `/data/owncloud.log` for info about this error.

Comment: I just figured out that with CloudFlare CSS + JavaScript Automatic Handle that's caused that problem in Firefox. It's a JavaScript Backend Cache Handling what is not default by CloudFlare. Still have this with Version 9 in OwnCloud.

Comment: I've used CloudFlare too, and I think it works horrible with ownCloud. All static files aren't loaded very well on every browser. So I let it go and just used my direct IP again. Besides, with LetsEncrypt and my own Apache I can get a far more secure web server than with CloudFlare.

Comment: Updated answer to include CloudFlare.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same Probem with my Owncloud on centos6. The only approach that worked was to save your config.php at a save place and do a backup of your mysql database. Then delete the whole owncloud directory and do a fresh install with yum. Now you need to create a temporary database and a temporary data directory. Finish the online installation so that you can log into the temporary account. Now activate all the 3rd party apps you had activated bevore. Otherwise you might have problems to activate the apps later on (including search calendar etc.)

Now having a working version of owncloud 8 you can recover the old data. Open the config.php and enter the instanceid, the secret, the data directory, db user, db key and in general all the abslutely nessessary data from the old installation. Now you should log into you owncloud as bevore.